# Calling a CommandController from ActionController in PHP/TYPO3 Extbase

Tags: php, typo3, extbase, actioncontroller

I wrote a Command Controller that handles data import from an URL.
pseudo-syntax is like this:

```
class ImportCommandController extends \TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Mvc\Controller\CommandController
{
  public function importCommand($auth){
    $data = file_get_content();
  }
}
```

this works.
But when I try to call that command from the Action Controller of my backend Module I get errors. 
Heres the code:
ActionController:

```
class ImportController extends \TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Mvc\Controller\ActionController
{
    /**
     * @var \Vendor\MyExt\Command\ImportCommandController importCommandCtrl
     * @inject
     */
    protected $importCommandCtrl;

    public function importAction()//($url,$usr,$pass)
    {
        //$this->importCommandCtrl = GeneralUtility::makeInstance('Vendor\MyExt\Command\ImportCommandController');
        $this->importCommandCtrl->testCommand();
    }
}
```

When I call `importAction()` like this, I get:

> "Call to a member function testCommand() on null"

When I uncomment the `makeInstance`, I get:

> "Call to a member function get() on null"

Sadly, this topic is documente rather poorly in the TYPO3 Docs.
Can someone help me on this or point me to the right direction?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd like to slightly alter the answer already given by René and add some code examples. I also recommend to put your import logic into a dedicated class, e.g. `ImportService`:

```
namespace Vendor\MyExt\Service;
use TYPO3\CMS\Core\SingletonInterface;
class ImportService implements SingletonInterface
{
    public function importData()
    {
       // import logic goes here
    }
}
```

You can now inject this class as a dependency of your CommandController and your ActionController:

```
class ImportController extends \TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Mvc\Controller\ActionController
{
    /**
     * @var \Vendor\MyExt\Service\ImportService
     * @inject
     */
     protected $importService;

    public function importAction()
    {
        $this->importService->importData();
    }
}

class ImportCommandController extends \TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Mvc\Controller\CommandControlle
{
    /**
     * @var \Vendor\MyExt\Service\ImportService
     * @inject
     */
    protected $importService;

    public function importCommand()
    {
        $this->importService->importData();
    }
}
```

Comment: In future use injectFunctions instead of annotation @injects

Comment: You are right. The inject methods do perform better than the parsing of the annotations. But they also bloat the example code, that's why I was using @inject here.

Comment: Wait, what? Inject annotation has an impact on performance? Doesn't the object cache take care of that?

Answer (score 1):

The use of an `CommandController` in an `ActionController` is not recommended because they have different envoiroment variables.

If you want to use some code on more position it's recommanded to use Utility classes.

So create an Class in the `my_ext/Classes/Utility/` directory call the class something like `ImportUtility` and try to code your import independed from some controller.